# Date input field DD/MM/YYYY with input type text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a date input but without using the **date-format** option of HTML5.

So let's say that my input is

```
<input type="text" id="dateField" />
```

Allowed characters only numbers and '`/`'

Is there any way to make this field accept only numbers and '`/`' (Without using the input `type="date"`)

**UPDATE** The purpose is not to use HTML5.

Comment: Why can't you simply use the date input type, since it defaults to `type=text` if the browser doesn't support the `date` type?

Comment: Because I also need to make it works as fine on the browsers that does not support the type=date .@DavidThomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTML5 date input:

```
<input type="date" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTML5 [input pattern attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) along with a Regular expression:

```
<input type="text" id="dateField" pattern="[\d/]"/>
```

Comment: The purpose is not to use any of the HTML 5 attr

Comment: @KainIndia that was never said - it sounds more like he doesn't want the date-format of a standard HTML5 date input

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<input name="number" onkeyup="if (/[^\d/]/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d/]/g,'')">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an input pattern supported in IE 11+

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}" />
```

If that still is not an option you should go for a javascript solution hooking to the change of the value of the field

```
var pattern = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/;
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keyup", function(ev){
  var value = ev.target.value;
  if(!pattern.test(value){
    //value of the field is not the one you are looking for
    // handle this
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to limit allowed characters in an input field.  You'll need to dig a bit deeper to restrict the actual format.

```js
$('#date').on('input', function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9/]/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="date" maxlength="10" />
```

You might also want to consider using a datepicker plugin (like [jQuery UI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) or similar)